# SailsJS model count by condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I using count method to counting total of records by conditions. And here is my code:

```
    Users.count({ 
      $or: [
        { username  : { "$regex": search } },
        { email     : { "$regex": search } },
        { lastName  : { "$regex": search } },
        { firstName : { "$regex": search } }
      ]
    }).exec(function (err, total) {
      console.log(total);
      return res.json({
        "sEcho": 0, 
        "iTotalRecords": total, 
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 7,
        "aaData": users
      });
    });
```

I always receive "total" is 0 values with any value of "search" param.
What are my mistakes and how to fix?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Users.count({ 
  or: [
    { username  : { contains: search } },
    { email     : { contains: search } },
    { lastName  : { contains: search } },
    { firstName : { contains: search } }
  ]
}).exec(function (err, total) {
  console.log(total);
  return res.json({
    "sEcho": 0, 
    "iTotalRecords": total, 
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 7,
    "aaData": users
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain the difference between the raw query form and what sails/waterline is expecting? That might help the OP understand in the future.

Comment: Thanks @num8er. I forgot that I don't work with model native.

Comment: @BlakesSeven seems like OP knows what was problem (: